# Restore NSUserDefaults data on Apple Watch app

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, apple-watch

I have an app, it uses `NSUserDefaults` to store some data from various views and then, later, restore this data in a specific view with all results previously calculated.

Well, now I want to make a new Apple Watch compatible version of this app, all I want is to take the same `NSUserDefaults` data already stored and show them on the Apple Watch screen.

I've used the following code, this code is already working on the iPhone App, but it does not work on the Watch-side of the app. What could be wrong?

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *consumo = [prefs stringForKey:@"consMedio"];
kml.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", consumo];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `standardUserDefaults`. Instead, create an AppGroup, and share the user defaults using `- [NSUserDefaults initWithSuiteName:]`. Use the same suite name to share.